# Trouble changing file/type

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new file on Visual code adding the .js at the end. Instead of adding JS at the front of the file name, it is giving the file ();.
The idea is to link to the an existing file but I believe it is not working because if this issue.
I would like the new file to have the JS in front instead of the ();
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Could you take a screenshot of your VSCode showing your file tree?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.